# How to get unique values from a ajax response

Tags: javascript, linq-to-entities, asp.net-ajax

This is my query. I pass the result of this query to ajax and display the needed values in UI. I get duplicate responses. How do I display unique response from ajax?

```
var env = (from c in _context.Customer
                   join r in _context.Request on c.Id equals r.CustomerId
                   join d in _context.DeploymentEnvironment on 
c.DeploymentEnvironmentId equals d.Id
                   join s in _context.Sizing on r.Tsize equals s.Id
                   join p in _context.Product on r.ProductId equals p.Id
                   join rg in _context.Regions on r.Region equals rg.RegionName
                   where (c.CustomerName == customername)
                   select new
                   {
                       s.Nomenclature,
                       r.Tsize,
                       rg.Id,
                       rg.RegionAbbr,
                       d.DeploymentEnvironment1,
                       c.DeploymentEnvironmentId,
                       p.ProductName,
                       r.ProductId

                   }).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: try using inner join

Comment: no it did not work

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).